# How to flag a cookie as secure which are not part of session in tomcat

Tags: google-chrome, tomcat, cookies

In one of our applications, we are having cross-domain cookies which are not working in chrome as that cookie is not secure as well as not HTTP Only. That cookie was generated by the tool and we don't have much control over that.

We tried multiple ways to overcome the problem.

1. Tried to set the below config in the web.xml file, but it doesn't work as it was not in session.

   ```
   <session-config>
        <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
        <cookie-config>
            <http-only>true</http-only>
            <secure>true</secure>
        </cookie-config>
    </session-config>
   ```
2. Tried with `<CookieProcessor sameSiteCookies="none" />` in context.xml too and with other attributes, no luck.

Please find the attached image for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `<cookie-config>` only applies to the cookie used to establish a session (`JSESSIONID` by default).

If your applications set cookies without the `secure` and `httpOnly` attributes, you can correct it with a [`Filter`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/4.0/apidocs/javax/servlet/filter):

```java
public class SecureCookieServletFilter implements Filter {

   private static class SecureCookieResponseWrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper {

      public SecureCookieResponseWrapper(HttpServletResponse response) {
         super(response);
      }

      @Override
      public void addCookie(Cookie cookie) {
         cookie.setSecure(true);
         cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
         super.addCookie(cookie);
      }

   }
   @Override
   public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
      // NOP
   }

   @Override
   public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
      final ServletResponse response = res instanceof HttpServletResponse ? new SecureCookieResponseWrapper((HttpServletResponse) res) : res;
      chain.doFilter(req, response);
   }

   @Override
   public void destroy() {
      // NOP
   }

}
```

Of course, you can implement the same logic in a custom [`CookieProcessor`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/util/http/CookieProcessor.html#generateHeader-javax.servlet.http.Cookie-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-), but that would be more difficult to distribute.